# ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false on Samsung S-edge S7

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, galaxy

I'm implementing drag and drop event on my app. Its working fine for all the other devices but shows error as - **ViewRootImpl: Reporting drop result: false** on particular **Samsung S7 edge** . I don't know what the problem is; does anyone have a solution for this?